# how to draw a shape using projective2d and a polygon in a video converted into frames

Tags: matlab, image-processing, video, polygon, matlab-cvst

Hi I am trying to extract frames from the camera and apply SURF detection in the frames acquired. The process works well except for I am not able to draw a shape or polygon around the detected object. In the estimate geometric transform I am able to get the projective2d tform. But when I am trying to draw a box polygon around the detected object i am not able to see any polygon or shape. Sometimes the polygon comes and disappears. Sometime the polygon is not accurate around the detected object.

The code for tform and polygon is as follows:

```
[tform, ~, ~,status] = ...
estimateGeometricTransform(matchedBoxPoints, matchedScenePoints, 'projective');

%box Polygon
boxPolygon = [1, 1;...                           % top-left
     size(boxImage, 2), 1;...                 % top-right
     size(boxImage, 2), size(boxImage, 1);... % bottom-right
     1, size(boxImage, 1);...                 % bottom-left
     1, 1]; 
newBoxPolygon = transformPointsForward(tform, boxPolygon);

% Display the frame
imshow(data)
hold on;
      line(newBoxPolygon(:, 1), newBoxPolygon(:, 2), 'Color', 'y');
title('Detected Box');
refreshdata;
```

Comment: There are detected SURF points. Let me know if there are any way to draw shapes around the detected surf points without using tform and find its center of detected object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the polygon disappears or is inaccurate, that could be because you are not finding enough matches, or because your matches are incorrect. You may want to see if that is the case, and if so, try to tweak the parameters of the `matchFeatures` function.

You can also use `insertShape` to draw the polygon directly into the image pixels.  But again, that assumes that you have good feature matches, and that you have computed the correct transformation.

Comment: Thank you..There was no enough match points. I handeled the error using an if else statement..Now I am able to display in a static text if there is not enough matched points...
Thanks a lot again.

Comment: You are welcome. Also, as I said before, you may be able to improve your results by tweaking the parameters of `detectSURFFeatures` and `matchFeatures`.

Comment: I get it.  And you may be able to get more matches and not have this error, if you increase the `'NumOctaves'` parameter of `detectSURFFeatures`, or if you increase `'MaxRatio'`  parameter of `matchFeatures`.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vdSaIjgXUIw&feature=youtu.be

here is the recording of the object detection. Its not so accurate. When I use number of octaves like below
        pts = detectSURFFeatures(img, 'MetricThreshold',200, ...
        'NumOctaves',3, 'NumScaleLevels',4);
I am getting error like below:

Expected input number 1, I, to be one of these types:

logical, uint8, int16, uint16, single, double

Instead its type was char.

Error in detectSURFFeatures>parseInputs (line 82)
validateattributes(I,{'logical', 'uint8', 'int16', 'uint16', ...

Comment: is there a way to have stability in detection

Comment: Sounds like your `img` variable is a string, instead of an image.  I would try setting `NumOctaves` to 6 or 8. Also, try increasing `MaxRatio`.